# How to retrieve email body and attachment text combined of an eml file using dtsearch?

Tags: c#, .net, dtsearch

I am processing an eml file and I want to retrieve email body and attachment text combined. Is dtsearch capable of doing this? 
I am using .NET framework and C# as programming language. I did look at the documentation of dtsearch but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

yes, eml is supported.  Available fields: To, CC, BCC, From, Sent Via, Sender, Recipient, Subject, Date, Attachments

http://support.dtsearch.com/dts0103.htm